# What is the loglevel for : printk ("Freeing initrd memory: %ldk freed\n", (end - start) >> 10);

Tags: kernel, logging, printk

In the kernel function call

```
printk ("Freeing initrd memory: %ldk freed\n", (end - start) >> 10);
```

No kernel log-level is mentioned. Then what will be the log level that will be taken by deafult?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer.

If no message log level is mentioned in printk function, the DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LOGLEVEL is used by the kernel. The second field in /proc/sys/kernel/printk shows the DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LOGLEVEL.